# Section text goes through footer on html/Css

Tags: html, css, css-float

I have a div id= "rightsection" that goes through my footer. I been trying to figure out how to fix this error all day searching and testing. Any help will be greatly appreciated.

Here's my html:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
   <html>
   <head>


      <meta charset="UTF-8" />
      <title>Bike the Mountains Tour</title>
      <script src="modernizr-1.5.js"></script>
      <link href ="mw_styles.css" rel = "stylesheet" type ="text/css">

   </head>

   <body>

        <div id="pageheader">
            <header>
                <h1><img src="mwlogo.png" alt="Mountain Wheels" /></h1>

            </header>
        </div>

      <div id ="nav">
         <ul>
            <li><a href="#">Home</a></li>
            <li><a href="#">Learn More</a></li>
            <li><a href="#">Testimonials</a></li>
            <li><a href="#">Route Maps</a></li>
            <li><a href="#">Register</a></li>
            <li><a href="#">Lodging</a></li>
            <li><a href="#">Meals</a></li>
            <li><a href="#">Training</a></li>
            <li><a href="#">Equipment</a></li>
            <li><a href="#">Forums</a></li>
            <li><a href="#">FAQs</a></li>
            <li><a href="#">Contact Us</a></li>
         </ul>
      </div>

        <div id="articleheader">
             <header>
                <h1 >Bike the Mountains Tour</h1>
            </header>
        </div>

        <div id="leftsection">
            <section>
                <p>
                The Bike the Mountains Tour rises from the town of Littleton, 
                Colorado and explores the Colorado Front Range. Our tour 
                crosses the Continental Divide twice, giving you the 
                opportunity to bike the highest paved roads in the 
                United States. This tour is a classic showcase of Colorado's 
                Rocky Mountain scenery.
                </p>

                <blockquote>
                <p>
                The Bike the Mountains Tour is <i>amazing</i>. I highly 
                recommend it and would gladly return.
                </p>
                <cite>&mdash; Steve H.</cite>
                </blockquote>


                <p>
                Not designed for the weekend cyclist, this tour is offered 
                only for those fit enough to ride high mountain passes. We 
                provide sag wagons and support. Your lodging and meals are 
                also part of the registration fee.
                We guarantee tough climbs, amazing sights, sweaty jerseys, 
                and lots of fun.
                </p>

                <p>
                This is the seventh year we've offered the Bike the Mountains 
                Tour. It is our most popular tour and riders are returning 
                again and again. Our experienced tour leaders will be there 
                to guide, help, encourage, draft, and lead you
                every stroke of the way. Come join us!
               </p>

            </section>
        </div>


        <div id="rightsection">
            <section>
                <h1>Itinerary</h1>

                <h2>Day 1</h2>
                <p>
                We start from the foothills above Littleton, Colorado, 
                promptly at 9am. The first day is a chance to get 
                your legs in shape, test your gearing, and prepare for 
                what's to come.
                </p>

                <h2>Day 2</h2>
                <p>
                Day 2 starts with a climb up Bear Creek Canyon to Lookout 
                Mountain, followed by a swift and winding descent into the 
                town of Golden. Refresh yourself at the famous Coors Brewery. 
                </p>

                <h2>Day 3</h2>
                <p>
                Day 3 takes you along the Peak to Peak Highway. This 
                55-mile route showcases the mountains of the Front Range, 
                providing amazing vistas from Golden Gate Canyon State Park 
                to Rocky Mountain National Park.
                </p>  

                <h2>Day 4</h2>
                <p>
                Now for the supreme challenge: Day 4 brings some real 
                high-altitude cycling through Rocky Mountain National Park 
                and up Trail Ridge Road. It's an amazing ride, high above 
                timberline, topping out at over 11,000 feet.
                </p>

               <h2>Day 5</h2>
                <p>
                We start Day 5 on the west side of the Continental Divide. 
                From Grand Lake, you'll bike to Winter Park and then over 
                Berthoud Pass, and back to the eastern side of 
                the Continental Divide.
                </p>

                <h2>Day 6</h2>
                <p>
                On Day 6 we ride 
                back to Littleton over Squaw Pass and Bear Creek and then
                enjoy a celebratory dinner as we share memories of a great
                tour.
                </p>

            </section>
        </div>

        <div id= "footer">
            <hr>
                <footer>
                    <address>
                        Mountain Wheels &nbsp;&bull;&nbsp;
                        Littleton, CO 80123 &nbsp;&bull;&nbsp;
                        (303) 555 - 5499
                    </address>
                </footer>
            </hr>   
        </div>

   </body>
</html>
```

And here's my css:

```
html
{
    position: relative;
    min-height: 100%;
}

body
{
    font-family:Tahoma, Geneva, sans-serif;
    margin: 0 0 0px;
}

#pageheader 
{
     width: 100%;
}

#articleheader
{
    font-size: 18px;
    font-weight: normal;
    letter-spacing: 7px;
    text-align: center;
}

#nav
{
    background-color: rgb(125,120,89);
    line-height: 3em;
    width: 10%;
    float:left;
}

#nav ul
{
    list-style-type: none;
}

#nav ul li:hover
{
    background-color: rgb(131, 121, 36);
    list-style-image: url(wheelmarker.png);
    color: yellow;
    color: rgba(255, 255, 255, 100%); 
}

#nav ul li a
{
    color: white;
    color: rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.5);
    text-decoration: none;
}

#leftsection
{
    float:left;
    width: 500px;
    padding: 10px;
}

#leftsection  section p 
{
    font-size: 22px;
}

#leftsection  section p:first-of-type:first-line
{
    text-transform: uppercase; 
}

#leftsection blockquote 
{
    width: 50%;
    background-color: rgb(131, 121, 36);
    color: white;
    font-size: 16px;
    font-family: Comic Sans MS, Times;
    border-radius: 1em;
    box-shadow: 10px 10px 5px #888888;
    float: right;

}

#leftsection blockquote p
{
    padding:5px;
    font-size: 16px;
    font-family: Comic Sans MS, Times;
}

#leftsection blockquote p:before
{
    content:open-quote;
}

#leftsection blockquote p:after
{
    content:close-quote;
}

#rightsection
{
    float: left;
    width: 200px;
    padding-right: 100px;
}

#rightsection  h1
{
    font-size: 22px;
    letter-spacing: 3px;
    font-weight: normal;
    text-align: center;
 }

#rightsection  h2
{
    font-size: 18px;
    font-weight: normal;
    text-align: right;
}

#rightsection  p
{

    font-size: 14px;
    text-align: justify;
    color: gray;
 }

 #footer
 {
    clear: both;
    width: 100%;
    position: absolute;
    height: 100px;
    clear: both;
    bottom: 0;


}

#footer footer address
{
    font-size: 16px;
    font-style: normal;
    text-align: center;
}
```

Comment: What does "goes through my footer" mean?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Make the `#footer` position relative instead of absolute.

Position `absolute` makes the element is positioned relative to its first positioned (not static) ancestor element.

Position `relative` makes the element is positioned relative to its normal position

```
#footer
 {
    clear: both;
    width: 100%;
   /* position: absolute; This is before */
    position: relative; /* MODIFICATION */
    height: 100px;
    clear: both;
    bottom: 0;


}
```

Here's a working Fiddle
https://jsfiddle.net/1s10qsry/

Answer (score 0):

It looks like you want #rightsection and #leftsection to float next to each other. You need to wrap them in their own containing div. Here I used the `<main>` tag:

https://jsfiddle.net/n1vm9pah/1/

EDIT: This will only work if the viewport is wider than the width of the floating divs. I would drop the `padding-right:100px` on #rightsection to help with this (fiddle updated).